# mysqlimport not able to add an to an existing field with primary key

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates, primary-key, mysqlimport

I tried using mysqlimport to load data into an existing record with a primary key. The csv also had the primary key same as the one in the record. But the insert was skipped due to duplicate primary key. Is there any way mysqlimport can be used to insert into such an existing record.

I do not want to do --replace as the data existing in the record is also necessary

Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to mess the terms "record" and "table"... these are two very different things.

Comment: Hi Tomas,thanks for your reply. Here by record I mean a single row in a table.

Comment: Really? So you really want to mysqlimport data to a *single row*?? You said *"I tried using mysqlimport to load data into an existing record"*...